# Get name of every 6th element out of string vector using R

Tags: r

Hi guys I am trying to use R for my data analysis. So i read in a data table and then I grap the columns which I need and get rid of all Blanks. I then build the mean value of 6 measurements and go on till the end. My problem is that that I also need the name of the sample. So I tried to get every 6th entry from the iC_name vector and transfer it to my iC-Name short Vector but that doesnt work at all. Any suggesdtions ?

```
daten  = read.csv(file="test.csv",head=TRUE,sep=",")
trash <- grep("Blank", daten[,3])
daten <- daten[-c(trash),]
iAv_temp <- grep("Intensity average" , daten[,2])
iAv <- daten[c(iAv_temp),]
iAv_name <- iAv[,3]
iAv <- iAv[,4]
iC_temp <- grep("Concentration average" , daten[,2])
iC <- daten[c(iC_temp),]
iC_name <-iC[,3]
iC <- iC[,4]
i=1
x=6
j=1
leng=length(iC)
leng_t=leng/6
iC_MW <- c(1:leng_t)

while (j<=leng_t)
{ 
  iC_name_short<-iC_name[i]  
  temp <- iC[i:x]
  iC_MW[j]<-median(temp)
  i<-i+6
  x<-x+6
  j<-j+1
}
```

Comment: Please provide reproducible dataset. Something like `dput(head(daten))` would be great.

Comment: Also the desired output would be good.  Since you say that the idea is to speed things up, maybe post the working code that is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `by` argument in `seq` function to do that. For example if want to extract every sixth letter

```
letters[seq(1,26,by =6)]

[1] "a" "g" "m" "s" "y"
```